# Android webView and google charts

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, google-pie-chart

Hi I need your help with a piechart from Google.
I have followed this [Google chart link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options) but it does not work.
If you test this code you can see that the legend and the piechart is far from each other.
I want them closer to each other. How can I do that?

One more thing: It seem like the height of the is fixed so if I add more rows to this chart it gets hidden...why?

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1.0", {"packages":["corechart"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart0);
function drawChart0() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn("string", "ITEM");
data.addColumn("number", "VALUE"); 
data.addRows([`
    <!-- If I add more rows here some of them gets hidden...why? -->
["'Test1'", 4.5],
["'Test2'", 21.2],
["'Test3'", 31.4],
["'Test4'", 0.0],
["'Test5'", 31.4],
["'Test6'", 0.0],
["'Test7'", 11.5]]);

var options = {
"title":"My Piechart test",
titleTextStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: '12', fontWidth: 'normal',bold: true},
sliceVisibilityThreshold:0,
is3D: true,
<!-- I want to have both legend and piechart beside each other -->
legend: {position: 'left',width:"100%",height:"100%"},
<!-- If I dont use "top", I can not see the title -->
chartArea:{left:2,top:20,position: 'left',width:"100%",height:"200%"}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("chart_div0"));chart.draw(data, options);}

</script></head><body>
<div id="chart_div0"></div>
</body></html>
```

I send this code into an webView with webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, contentHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
I don't think that the webview is wrong becuase if you try this html code you can actually see that the problem is there as well. So I concentrate on the html code it self.

Thanks in advance for all your help:)

Comment: Did you manage to display it?